# How to Detect a TPopupMenu's OnClose (OnPopDown) Event in Delphi applications

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I can write some code inside TPopupMenu's OnPopUp event. But I also need another event for OnPopDown. Is there any way to do it using Delphi 10.3.3?

Comment: Have you seen http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=45678 ?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Andrzej In what way exactly? Please be more specific. That technique (overriding `TPopupListEx`) *does* work. I've used it before.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I followed the exact steps, compiled successfully but captions didn't change, using Delphi 10.3.3.

Comment: @Andrzej What do captions have to do with detecting the menu closing? You are confusing the issue now.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sorry I mean the code in cjcsoft website, it should change the caption when menu closing is detected, but it doesn't. Andreas Rejbrand's answer works OK.

Comment: @Andrzej worked fine for me when I used it before. We can't see the code you are using in your project, maybe you are not applying it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various options you can try.

## Approach 1

In the simpler case when you have a particular control whose context menu you need to track, you can handle its `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message manually:

```
  protected
    procedure WMContextMenu(var Message: TWMContextMenu);
      message WM_CONTEXTMENU;
```

where (for example)

```
procedure TForm1.WMContextMenu(var Message: TWMContextMenu);
begin
  if
    Assigned(PopupMenu)
      and
    (ClientRect.Contains(ScreenToClient(Message.Pos)) or (Message.Pos = Point(-1, -1)))
  then
  begin
    Windows.Beep(200, 500); // pre-popup code
    if (Message.XPos = -1) and (Message.YPos = -1) then // Menu key or Shift+F10
      with ClientToScreen(Point(0, 0)) do
        PopupMenu.Popup(X, Y)
    else
      PopupMenu.Popup(Message.XPos, Message.YPos);
    Windows.Beep(400, 500); // post-popup code
  end
  else
    inherited;
end;
```

The test `ClientRect.Contains(ScreenToClient(Message.Pos))` is necessary so that you don't "overwrite" the scrollbar's own context menu. Also, you need to consider the case when the context menu is opened using the keyboard (e.g. menu key or Shift+F10).

## Approach 2

If this is not enough for you, you could create your own `TPopupMenu` child class and override its `Popup` method, which is virtual. Add a `DoPopdown` method and call it at the end (following the design of the `DoPopup` method).

To quickly test this approach, you can use an interposer class:

```
type
  TPopupMenu = class(Vcl.Menus.TPopupMenu)
    procedure Popup(X, Y: Integer); override;
  end;
```

implemented as

```
{ TPopupMenu }

procedure TPopupMenu.Popup(X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;
  Windows.Beep(400, 500); // post-popup code
end;
```

But of course it is nicer to create a true descendant class (`TPopupMenuEx`, perhaps?) that you register in the IDE. Add an `FOnPopdown: TNotifyEvent` private field, a `DoPopdown` protected function, and an `OnPopdown` published property. This precisely mimics the `OnPopup` mechanism.

Needless to say, this approach also works with a `TTrayIcon`'s menu.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work for me. Can you change the code for only PopupMenu1?

Comment: @Andrzej: What doesn't work? In the first approach, you need to change the control, not the popup menu.

Comment: pre-popup code and post-popup code not triggered I suppose

Comment: Is it a single, particular control, whose context menu you need to track?

Comment: I have a VCL application. I dropped a PopupMenu1. I can add PopupMenu1's OnPopup event but I also need to add an event when PopupMenu1 is closed.

Comment: Yes, I know. But you must also have attached the popup menu to some control or have added code to manually display it. For instance, maybe you have set the form's `PopupMenu` property to `PopupMenu1`, or you have a `TRichEdit` control named `RichEdit1`, whose `PopupMenu` peoperty you have set to `PopupMenu1`. Or maybe you have some code that calls `PopupMenu1.Popup` manually. Which is it?

Comment: You can attach a single popup menu to several controls (e.g. five rich edit controls, two buttons, and one edit box). If so, my first approach will not work. That's why I wrote "In the simpler case when you have a particular control whose context menu you need to track [...]".

Comment: Oh sorry. It's attached to Form1. Form1's PopupMenu is set PopupMenu1.

Comment: If so, my approach will work just fine. You need to add my first code snippet to the declaration of `TForm1` in the `interface` section. The second snippet should go in the `implementation` section. That will work. I promise. When yo right-click the form, you will hear a low-frequency beep before the popup menu is shown and a high-frequency beep when it is closed. You are supposed to replace these beeps with the code you want to execute before and after the menu is shown.

Comment: No problem! :-)

Comment: If the VCL was kind enough to pass the originating window's handle to the handler, one could use OnContextPopup instead of a message handler. Currently it would be quite clumsy to find out it the context request resulted from a child control without an associated popup menu or the form itself - if possible at all. OTOH, if it's OK that non popup-ed controls launch the form popup, the event handler can be used.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Can't you use `Sender`?

Comment: @Andreas - Nope, after the control *perform*s the message to the form, the sender is the form.

Answer (score 1):

In newer version (e.g. 11.2 Alexandria) `TPopupMenu` has an build in `OnClose` event